# QIcon Using ndarray

Tags: pyqt5

In some interface using `PyQt5`, let `button` be a QPushButton. If we want to set an icon for the button using a given saved image `image.jpg`, we usually write:

`button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("image.jpg"))`

However, if I am given an n-dimensional numpy array `array` which also represents an image, I cannot simply write `button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(array))` as it will give an error message. What should I do to instead? (saving the array as an image is not in consideration as I want large amount of arrays to be made into PushButton)

Edit:

For a typical situation, consider:

```
import numpy

array = numpy.random.rand(100,100,3) * 255
```

Then `array` is a square array representing an image. To see this, we can write (we do not have to use `PIL` or `Image` to solve our problem and this is just a demonstration):

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(imarray.astype('uint8')).convert('RGBA')
```

Reference:[100x100 image with random pixel colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261851/100x100-image-with-random-pixel-colour)

I want to make this fixed array an icon.

Comment: It depends on what shape is used for the array and the way pixels are stored. How is the array created? Are you using opencv?

Comment: I have updated the question. I have no problem with using opencv.

Comment: If you're using PIL, you should look for the ImageQt submodule.

Comment: We do not have to use PIL. In fact, I perfer opencv if possible. I use PIL as an example just for the purpose of demonstrating my array indeed represents an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build a QImage -> QPixmap -> QIcon:

```py
import numpy as np

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

app = QApplication([])

array = (np.random.rand(1000, 1000, 3) * 255).astype("uint8")

height, width, _ = array.shape
image = QImage(bytearray(array), width, height, QImage.Format.Format_RGB888)
# image.convertTo(QImage.Format.Format_RGB32)

button = QPushButton()
button.setIconSize(image.size())
button.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap(image)))
button.show()

app.exec_()
```